# How does HashMap in Java use equals() and hashCode() to find objects?

Tags: java, hashmap, equals

I have defined a Point class as shown below, overriding the `equals()` and `hashCode()`. I was expecting that in the `main()` method, "Key Found" will be printed, but it's not.

It was my understanding that Java uses the `equals()` and `hashCode()` to add or find objects in a `HashMap`. I am not sure what am I doing wrong here.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Point {
  int row = 0;
  int col = 0;

  public Point(int row, int col) {
    this.row = row;
    this.col = col;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return String.format("[%d, %d]", row, col);
  }

  public boolean equals(Point p) {
    return (this.row == p.row && this.col == p.col);
  }

  public int hashCode() {
    return 31 * this.row + this.col;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<Point, Integer> memo = new HashMap<>();
    Point x = new Point(1, 2);
    Point y = new Point(1, 2);
    memo.put(x, 1);

    if (x.equals(y))
      System.out.println("x and y are equal");

    System.out.println("Hashcode x= " + x.hashCode() + " Hashcode y= " + 
                       y.hashCode());

    if (memo.containsKey(y)) {
      System.out.println("Key found");
    }
  }
}

output
x and y are equal
Hashcode x= 33 Hashcode y= 33
```

Comment: Add `@Override` tags to your overriden methods and it gets quite clear what you did wrong.

Comment: do you understand why this method: public boolean equals(Point p) {
   return (this.row == p.row && this.col == p.col);
} is not what/how you want (it) ?

Comment: Also, despite that you need to override Object#equals correctly, please have a look at the documentation for a correct equals implementation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)). If the other point is `null`, you will get a NullPointerException, altough `x.equals(null)` should return `false`.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you aren't actually overriding the `equals()` method. The [`equals()` method that you are trying to override](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) takes in an `Object` as a parameter, not a `Point` object. Therefore, the `equals()` method that you implemented isn't actually called.

Comment: @TanM no problem. Consider accepting the answer. :-)